# bind gunicorn to IPv6 localhost - binds to '[::]:8000' instead of '[::1]:8000'

Tags: ipv6

According to [gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation) and other sources across the web including other questions in SO The correct value of the "localhost" or "loopback" for an IPv6 address is the value `[::1]` but when binding it in gunicorn command:

`gunicorn -b '[::1]:8003' myserver:app`

will not bind it, and will return the following errors when it try to start:

```
[2021-01-08 14:18:41 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-01-08 14:18:41 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('::1', 8003)
[2021-01-08 14:18:41 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second
```

this repeats and then the operation is aborted.
when binding with `[::]:8003` the same command works and server is available both on ipv6 and ipv4. is this an unexpected behaviour of gunicorn, or is this how it should be?

Comment: maybe other program already use this addres. Did you try with different port? Did you try to open this address in web browser?

Comment: @furas  i've checked with netstat nothing is on this port. it happens with any port i would assign instead (8080, 8000, 5000 etc.)

Comment: did you manage to find a workaround?